# How to filter IPv4 IPs in bash

Tags: bash, dns, dig

How do I filter IPv4 IPs from data in bash?

For example:

*command:*

```
dig www.ign.com A +short
```

*return:*

```
www.ign.com.edgesuite.net.
a1005.g.akamai.net.
2.20.255.80
2.20.255.78
```

And I want to make a bush script to put the return result to a txt file named "a.list",which contain:

```
2.20.255.80
2.20.255.78
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
dig www.ign.com A +short | grep -oE "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b" > a.list
```

in your bash script. or refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482951/extracting-ip-address-from-a-line-from-ifconfig-output-with-grep).

I think you mean "bash" not "[bush](http://bush.sourceforge.net/)", right?

Comment: Yep..I spelled the word "bash" wrongly....Thank you a lot!